# Tweaking the list of selected items from CheckBoxList controls

Tags: c#, variables, user-controls

Sorry, I'm still a C# n00b.  I've got this code the will retrieve the items from my controls.  The problem is, the final SQL string is a bit off.  There's an extra comma in my s2 variable.

Here's my code-behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //String with all selected items in ListBox lstFilter
    var selectedQuery = lstFilter.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
    string txtlstFilter = String.Join("','", selectedQuery).TrimEnd();

    //String with all selected items in CheckBoxList cbFields1
    string s1 = string.Empty;
    new List<ListItem>(cbFields1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected)).ForEach(x => s1 += string.Format("{0}, ", x.Value));

    //String with all selected items in CheckBoxList cbFields2
    string s2 = string.Empty;
    new List<ListItem>(cbFields2.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(j => j.Selected)).ForEach(y => s2 += string.Format("{0}, ", y.Value));
 //   textBox1.Text = s;  

    var strSQL = "SELECT " + s1 + s2 + " FROM vwClaimRoster WHERE " + cboFilterOption.SelectedValue + " in ('" + txtlstFilter + "');";

}
```

And here's what strSQL ends up being (based on what I've selected):

"SELECT MgrName, Division, Routing, Dept, ExpCtr, State, EEName, Argus, CCP, ChkRework,  FROM vwClaimRoster WHERE Dept in ('ACCOUNT ADVOCACY','BILLING CONTROL','CCF CLAIM');"

As you can see, I need to get rid of that last comma in my list of fields (the one after ChkRework).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, use `Union` to join the ListItems, then `string.Join` to get the comma-separated list (instead of the `ForEach`):

```
string selectList = string.Join(", ", 
     cbFields1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
         .Union(cbFields2.Items.Cast<ListItem>())
         .Where(i => i.Selected)
         .Select(x => x.Value)
 );
```

For the second part, just add the single quotes to `string.Join`, and also before/after:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT " + selectList + " FROM vwClaimRoster WHERE " + cboFilterOption.SelectedValue
    " in ('" + String.Join("','", selectedQuery).TrimEnd() + "');";
          ^                 ^ ^                               ^
```

Comment: Minty-fresh!  I ended up figuring out the second part just after I posted, but that first part was driving me nuts.  Thanks!